# Google Maps Activity isn't fully loading

Tags: android, maps

i have some problem with the ordinary Google Maps Activity (New Project -> Google Maps Activity). So i start a new project with this activity and set the API key in *google_maps_api.xml*. Now if i run the app on emulator, the app is starting and i get an grey screen with location names. Sometimes there is also a thin blue triangle of color which graphs sea or land. If i try to move on the map the app crashes after 1 second. Please watch the picture [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaWIU.png) i attached.

*I checked the API level of my app and emulator
*I don't touched the code for this starter example
*No error occurs

Any idea?

EDIT: The app works on the real phone.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far and logs. To understand how to ask a good question, go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering so late. Thank you metahost for your activity. 
I am new in android/java, so it is not easy for me to define my questions so detailed that an advanced developer understand my problems.

**But i learn and find the solution on my on.**

The problem was in getting the API key. 
I knew that i needed a limited API key for android. The problem was that i used the wrong SHA fingerprint.

Everything works now.